# How to format my batch file correctly

Tags: batch-file

I've been at this for a few hours now. I'm finally giving in and asking for help. What I'm trying to do is use a batch file to get my Truecrypt volume mounted, then open Dropbox. When both of these things are done, executing the batch file the second time will exit Dropbox, then dismount the Truecrypt volume. Everything works correctly except for the exiting of Dropbox. I can't for the life of me, get it to exit Dropbox then dismount the volume. It skips right over the taskkill and just dismounts the volume. I've tried it a variety of different ways which *should* be working, but for some reason are not. The command window is saying taskkill isn't recognized as a command, but that's obviously bull. =\

```
@echo off
Set Drive=Z
Set Path="C:\Users\DK\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox.bak"
Set TrueCrypt="C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe"

IF EXIST %Drive%: GoTo Dismount
GOTO Mount

:Dismount
taskkill /F /IM "dropbox.exe"
%TrueCrypt% /d %Drive% /f /w /q /s
exit

:Mount
%TrueCrypt% /v /l %Drive% %Path% /q

echo Waiting for volume...
:keepwaiting
ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 > nul
if not exist Z:\ goto keepwaiting
start "Dropbox" "C:\Users\DK\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\Dropbox.exe"
exit
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your `taskkill` command. Some invisible characters maybe? (Just a wild guess). Try it with `.exe`. Try it from the command prompt. It's an 'external' command (an executable file), so maybe it got deleted somehow (but please don't ask me why and how).

Comment: @AndriyM taskkill works fine on it's own, but not when I try to put it near the Truecrypt dismount. Adding .exe didn't work. Really there's no logical reason as to why it shouldn't be working. I hate when things like this happen.

Comment: Yeah, that's very annoying. In confusing situations I often give up on trying to find out the cause of the problem in hand, and instead concentrate on finding a solution that works. And in a case like this one I might start with putting the `taskkill` command in a separate batch script, just that single line. If it worked, I'd then add some more lines (like `@ECHO OFF`, labels & `GOTO`s), then more, until it slowly turned into what it should be in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Never** use Path as your own variable! Change `Set Path="C:\Users\DK\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox.bak"` to something like Set DropboxPath="C:\Users\DK\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox.bak"

Taskkill.exe is in system32 but windows can only find it if it is listed in %Path%.

Tips:

- It is probably a good idea to call `setlocal` as the second line in your script so your variables don't leak out of the batch file.
- Never `set` path, pathext, temp, tmp, windir, SystemRoot, SystemDrive, OS, PROCESSOR_* or NUMBER_OF_* unless you really know what you are doing.
- Use `exit /B` or `goto :EOF` instead of `exit` if you don't want to close a console window while you are testing...

Comment: Thank you very much! :D I found some of this code on the Dropbox forums and oddly enough the person had nothing about exiting Dropbox in their code, even though you're supposed to exit before dismounting the drive the folder is in. So I added taskkill myself, not knowing about %path%.